# Change list comprehension to generator to prevent memory error

Tags: python, pandas

**What I have:**

A dataframe as the following

```
         I.D         Score
1         11          26
3         12          26
5         13          26
6         14          25
```

multiply a million rows....

**What I am trying to do**:

1) Pass both columns to a function called `Points` and create a list called `players`. credits to @jezrael

```
players = [Points(int(a),b) for a, b in zip(score['I.D'],score['Score'])]
```

2) Pass the list to another basic function, that simply uploads the whole list

```
upload_to_scoreboard(players)
```

**What I get**

```
MemoryError
```

I believe that passing the whole list consisting of million rows to the next function causes it to run out of memory. how can I modify the code to pass the list to the `upload_to_scoreboard` without causing memory error?

Comment: Have you tried `score[['I.D', 'Score']].values.tolist()` ?

Comment: @jpp no I have not

Comment: @jpp you mean try this way `upload_to_scoreboard(score[['I.D', 'Score']].values.tolist())`

Comment: @jpp how do you pass a single column as an int in this case ?

Comment: So you mean that step 2 above crashes while step 1 runs fine? Maybe provide the code in `upload_to_scoreboard` then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use generator instead of list.

To do so replace `[]` by `()` to surround your list comprehension.

`players = [Points(int(a),b) for a, b in zip(score['I.D'],score['Score'])]` loads the entire list in memory. To avoid it you can use a generator. Generators are kind of list but with the difference that every item is computed and loaded in memory only when it is itered, and it is unloaded once you no longer use it.
However in your case, the upload_to_score_board function must accept a such data structure and don't use list specificities.

To know more about generators vs list, read this : https://medium.freecodecamp.org/python-list-comprehensions-vs-generator-expressions-cef70ccb49db#741d

Comment: @Matthew even if it does not help you, I think it may help other users. If somebody more skilled than me write a better answer, select this answer as the best one. One of the goal of SO is to help not only the guy who posted the question but also the whole community.

Comment: yes, but your answer is not detailed enough. Can you kindly elaborate exactly on how to use it ? and i will select it as best answer, thank you.